# R: Coloring Rectangles depending on Values of Data frame

Tags: r, plot, colors, rect

First an explanation of what I am looking for, then some reproducible simple code.

In my example I have a simple plot without any lines but just with 10 rectangles.
My goal is to color the 10 rectangles either green, red or yellow. 
the color of the rectangles results from the values of the last 10 observations of the column x of the preinstalled data set randu.

1. Should the value be >0.7 the rectangle should be red
2. Should the value be >= 0.7 and <= 0.5 the rectangle should be green
3. Should the value be <0.5 the rectangle should be yellow

I have a vector defined called farben that consists of 3 hexcodes (yellow red sand green)

```
data(randu)
farben<-c("#FFFF00", "#00FF00", "#FF0000")
plot(c(0, 20), c(0, 40), type= "n", xlab = "", ylab = "")
for (i in 0:10) {
rect(i, 0, (i+1), 5, border = "black", col=farben)}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick. The code doesn't use the vector `farben`, but directly assigns the colors based on the criteria you listed:

```
plot(c(0, 20), c(0, 40), type= "n", xlab = "", ylab = "")
for (i in 0:10) {
  randu_value <- tail(randu[, "x"], 11)[i+1]

  if(randu_value > 0.7) color <- "#FF0000" 
  if(randu_value <= 0.7 & randu_value >= 0.5) color <-  "#00FF00"
  if(randu_value < 0.5) color <- "#FFFF00"

  rect(i, 0, (i+1), 5, border = "black", col=color)
}
```